# jQuery restore element back to original position after 'detach'ing it

Tags: jquery, anchor, restore, detach

I designed an accordion like catogory selection which uses another 'div' to show details after you select an item. I'm using jQuery to move the 'details' box below the selected category item:

```
 var detailsDiv = $('#category-details').detach();
 detailsDiv.insertAfter('#category-item');
```

Now I want to move the '#category-details' div back to it's original position. What's the best way to do this?